# How to login using Google Plus API using C#.Net from asp.net code behind and get user name

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to login using Google Plus API using C#.Net from asp.net code behind and get user name

Please give me some idea.

Note:- i don't want to expose client id & secret to end user by keeping those in .aspx file

Thanks,

Vijay

Comment: Do you have a compute engine account?  because if you try to do that on app engine it'll fail.... App engine doesn't support C#

Answer (score 0):

with **OAuth** you can do that, I recommend reading about OAuth and how you should do it.

I LEAVE THIS LINK FROM GOOGLE SITE DEVELOPERS
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Quick-start sample app for C# / .NET [guide](https://developers.google.com/+/web/samples/csharp) that should help you get started with using the Google+ Sign-In button via C#/.NET.

You may also be interested in this .NET Google API Client Libraries [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth) describing how to use them with OAuth 2.0.